# Загрука Яндекс карты блокирует поток кода

Tags: javascript, html, yandex-maps-jsapi, асинхронность

Вставляю карту Яндекс на сайт, он блокирует поток код, отчего gsap анимация начинает работать с сильными рывками, учитывая, что src iframе'a прописан асинхронным.
Так же пробовал динамически вставлять html из js через setTimeout, ничего не меняется, всё блокируется.
Поделитесь, пожалуйста, как лучше вставить карту, чтобы она загружалась исключительно после загрузки основного контента страницы

Comment: window.onload( => {}_

Comment: А может тогда лучше в вашей анимации gsap прописать "onComplete: init"? https://webformyself.com/ispolzovanie-gsap-3-dlya-veb-animacii/#:~:text=%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B5.-,%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2,-%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC